# How to replace multiple substrings where one or more substrings are part of other substrings?

Tags: java, string

I have a `String` which contains words like "sum" and "sumall". I need to replace "sum" with 'B' and "sumall" with 'A'. For my convenience, I convert them all to uppercase, however when I replace them all one by one, say first change all "sum" into 'B' and then change all "sumall" into 'A', then I get weird results. All "sum" is converted into 'B' and all "sumall" becomes "Ball" which is something I don't want. How do I change them correctly?

Comment: Show some code, please

Comment: Do you want only whole words to be replaced or should something like "summon" become "Bmon" as well?

Comment: It is purely for an assignment of my university, where we were given an assignment to replace strings, and I encountered an issue like this, not exactly the same though. I don't have any code to show but I guess my question is already clear enough about what I exactly want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have weird results because you do it in the wrong order. Let's assume that your input is

> "sumall sum"

and you expect your output to be

> "A B"

Now, if you first replace sum with B, then you end up with

> "Ball B"

and it will not help to replace sumall with A in an already damaged `String`. So, assuming that you have a `String[][]` which contains pairs of what needs to be replaced with what, then you will need to sort it by one `String` being a substring of another as a comparison check.

Let's sort using a comparator:

```
Collections.sort(yourInput, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String a, String b) {
        if ((a == null) || (b == null) || (a.equals(b))) return 0;
        if (a.indexOf(b) >= 0) return -1;
        if (b.indexOf(a) >= 0) return 1;
        return 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash thanks for pointing that out. I voted to reopen the question and off course upvoted your answer yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

First replace `sumall` with `A` and then replace `sum` with `B`. You can chain them together as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello sumall hi sum. sumall and sum are different".replace("sumall", "A")
                .replace("sum", "B").toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
HELLO A HI B. A AND B ARE DIFFERENT
```

Comment: How does your answer scale for additional replacements with the same prefixes?

Comment: Thanks it worked, the approach i used is I saved all the words to be replaced in an array, and arranged them in descending order according to their length size, so the word with greatest length was at the top, and replaced them in that order, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the replacements in your question are just an example to illustrate the error and you're probably interested in a solution that works for other replacements as well.

As you mentioned you'd like to replace words you could use regular expressions to match the desired replacements only if they occur as whole word and not as substring in other words (If you really have the requirement to work on substrings as well a generic solution would involve sorting all replacements based on their common prefix).

For whole words (word corresponds to an arbitrary sequence of alpha-numeric characters) the code below should work:

```
final Map<String, String> replacements = Map.of(
    "sum", "B",
    "sumall", "A");
final String test = "hello sumall hi sum. sumall and sum are different";
String result = test; 
for (var replacementEntry : replacements.entrySet()) {
  result = result.replaceAll("([\\W]+)" + Pattern.quote(replacementEntry.getKey()) + "([\\W]+)",
      "$1" + replacementEntry.getValue() + "$2");
}
        
System.out.println(result);
```

Output:

```
hello A hi B. A and B are different
```